# How to get samples of different paths?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, computer-science, graph-theory

Say I have a "semi" directed, weighted, graph (some edges are undirected, some are directed).

Consider two nodes, A and B. Consider the set of all paths that take me from node A to node B.

I essentially want X samples of all these paths. I don't want these samples to be "too close" to the ideal path. Essentially, I want them relatively spread out over the space of solutions. I do want to include cyclic paths, which I know makes the set of possible paths infinite. Therefore, I want the paths to be relatively close to the ideal path, but still not too close. This is obviously a very vague, non-rigourous description of this aspect of the problem, which is why if possible, I would like to be able to specify some parameter that lets me control how close to the ideal my samples are.

These are the solutions I have thought of so far:

1) Use some kind of algorithm that gives me the X shortest paths. The problem with this is the samples are all too similar to the ideal path.

2) Do the following:

```
     a) Run A*/Dijikstra's to find the ideal path.
     b) Remove X% of the edges that form the ideal path.
     c) Run A*/Dijistra's again to find the second sample. The fact that a portion of the edges have been removed from the ideal path, should mean that this second sample should be quite different.
     d) Remove X% of the edges that form the second sample.
     e) Repeat.
```

The problem with this is that I'm worried that for a large number of samples (10000+), a very large number of edges will be removed, making the samples taken later on to be very, very different from the ideal path.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to better approach the problem?

The graph is quite big (100000+ nodes and edges). The algorithm's speed and performance is very important, however I can do a very large amount of preprocessing beforehand, if necessary.

**Why I need to do this:** Essentially, in our "actual graph", each edge contains two weights. We want to find a path that maximizes the second weight, while being under the constraint that the path length in terms of the first weight does not violate a constraint (i.e. the path length isn't longer that 20% of the ideal path in terms of the first weight). It's impossible to solve non-heuristically in a reasonable amount of time, so we are essentially sampling a large number of random paths, eliminating those that violate the constraint and picking the best sample in terms of the second weight. We put a lot of time into this problem and this is the only solution that gives us anything close to a reasonable computation time

Comment: Why is it important to find 'none optimal solutions'? Including paths that includes 'loops'? I am just curious as to what problem you are interested in? I have no help to supply at all!

Comment: @RyanVincent Essentially, each edge contains two weights. We want to find a path that maximizes the second weight, while being under the constraint that the path length in terms of the first weight does not violate a constraint (i.e. the path length isn't longer that 20% of the ideal path in terms of the first weight). It's impossible to solve non-heuristically in a reasonable amount of time, so we are essentially sampling a large number of random paths, eliminating those that violate the constraint and picking the best sample in terms of the second weight.

Comment: @RyanVincent We put a lot of time into this problem and this is the only solution that gives us anything close to a  reasonable computation time.

Comment: May i suggest that you add the comment to your question as it clarifies what you have considered and may help others to appreciate what you are trying to do and what you have considered.

Comment: Have you tried this in the 'StackExchange' 'maths' group? I have no idea whether you know about them. This is all so 'way beyond my field of expertize'. I really was just curious. see:  'alice' and 'rabbit hole' ;-/

Comment: @RyanVincent Yup, I did! Unfortunately, I got no responses.

Comment: So you have an answer to this question: 'i.e. the path length isn't longer that 20% of the ideal path in terms of the first weight'. How did you find the 'ideal path'?  How did you find the 20% limit? Because your final solution seems to depend on this?  Have you rephrased an 'np complete' problem? I am so guessing here. Are you trying to solve the 'travelling salesman' problem?

Comment: @RyanVincent Well, the ideal path (or the shortest path) can be easily found using a number of algorithms - we choose to use A*. As for the 20% limit, that's just a number I came up with off the top of my head. The actual number varies every time and depends on something else entirely. I am not trying to solve the travelling salesman problem, it's just path finding with two edge weights. Finally, I'm not sure if the problem is NP complete.

Comment: If by "ideal path" you mean the shortest path, you should say that instead somewhere early in your question. It looks like you have about seven references to the ideal path, and how things are close or not close to the ideal path before you suggest that maybe ideal means shortest.